# Posix Semaphores source code location in linux

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel

I have started learning semaphores concept in Operating System.
I am using POSIX semaphores in linux. I have used sem_init(), sem_wait() and sem_post() for initializing, decrementing and incrementing semaphore variables.

I have seen Function declarations given in semaphore.h file.

But I couldn't find source code of these above functions. I have gone through some kernel source files but I couldn't find them. From where can I get these source code files?

I am using linux 3.6.11-4 kernel.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the glibc source: that implements the POSIX C interface and only passes syscalls down to the kernel where necessary. For example, [sem_init.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/sem_init.c;h=575b661f624cbb2aff0bf6f18187e063e9655443;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the older ["SysV IPC"](http://linux.die.net/man/7/svipc) semaphores (`semctl`, `semop`, etc), the POSIX semaphore API is not implemented directly by the kernel.  Instead, the C library implements it on top of the [`futex`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/futex) generic synchronization primitive.

The code you are looking for is in the [`nptl`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=nptl) subdirectory of the GNU libc source tree.  You may also have to go digging around in [`sysdeps`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=sysdeps) to find all of it.